# Access to the dex task is now impossible

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, synchronization

Error while trying run the project

Error:Access to the dex task is now impossible, starting with 1.4.0
1.4.0 introduces a new Transform API allowing manipulation of the .class files.
See more information: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/transform-api

Comment: solution is obvious(even for not programmers): Write to your gradle's addin developers(the one that causing this error) about it and wait till their fix it ... meanwhile use older gradle plugin ... eventually, if plugin is open source, you could try to fix it by yourself